# node.js firebase get data return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem with getting data from firebase to index.php.
firebase.js have a getting data function, that return to index.php.
I've got **[object Object]** not variable in index.php. How to get var from firebase.js?

**index.php**

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getData();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**firebase.js**

```
var db = firebase.database();
function getData() {
    var content = '';
    var ref = db.ref("user");

    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            var key = snapshot.key;
            content += key + '<br />';
        }
    });
    return $('#demo').text(content);
}
```

After modifications i've got var from console.log(content) like this:

```
undefined
[2018-02-13T10:30:06.110] [DEBUG] default - Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
user1<br />
user1<br />user2<br />
user1<br />user2<br />user3<br />
user1<br />user2<br />user3<br />user4<br />
user1<br />user2<br />user3<br />user4<br />user5<br />
```

Comment: How is this PHP related?

Comment: Content is just an object. You need to write out the attributes of the object that you want, not the object itself. Therefore, you can try to console.log content and view in the console of your browser what content you actually want to print out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with how your code is set up
replace the content of your script tag with `getData();`

Replace the `getData` function with:

```
function getData() {
    var content = '';
    var ref = db.ref("user");

    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
            var key = snapshot.key;
            content += key + '<br />';
            $('#demo').innerHTML = content;
        }

    });

}
```

The problem is that your getData function is returning an object which javascript automatically converts to [object Object] when it is used where a string is expected.

Also the callback on the `"child_added"` event is called some time after the `getData` function ends so you need to make your modifications inside the call back for it to actually work.

Comment: thanks, it's works but now i getting **undefined**. what modifications must I make? could you help me, please? **edit:** so, i still got **undefined**, even if i change value in var content.

Comment: what do you see if you put `console.log(content)` just before the `$('#demo').innerHTML` line?

Comment: I updated main post. look please. it's look good but in index.php i've got **undefined**

Comment: I edited my post. you are looking at the wrong log. Look in the browser console and see what it says. It should say the same thing as we see here. if it just says 'undefined' then try replacing the `$('#demo')...` line with $('#demo').innerHTML = 'test';

Comment: i haven't noticed. console.log say the same. I replaced on `$('#demo').innerHTML = 'test';` but still i see **undefined**. i've got first value. if i had `$('#demo').append(content);` I got all values. how to return "last" value when are variable completed?